# Google popular times in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-places-api

Google provided the latest Api "Popular times" to get data regarding to the specific time a particular business or else is busy or popular. However it comes with python implementation.

Does anyone know a way to use the google popular times api inside a Node.js project?

https://github.com/m-wrzr/populartimes
this  link gets you  for a python code..how to include or how we can get api for node project

Comment: Look like it is not available as a web service yet.

Comment: is there any way to get solution

Comment: only solution I can think of is use Python is separate module and expose the library functionality as decoupled microservice

Answer (score 0):

You could try the foot traffic API service [BestTime.app](https://BestTime.app), which also works with Node.JS. Unfortunately, it's paid, but they offer a free test account.

BestTime.app provides foot traffic data almost similar to Google Popular Times and Foursquare data, but with more functionality. You can also analyze and filter foot traffic data of multiple places in an area. So you can for example filter places and show only bars that are busy on Friday evening, or show only supermarkets that are quiet on Sunday morning.

You can view the data through their website tools (e.g. on a heatmap), or get the same data through their software API ([Software API tutorial](https://blog.besttime.app/beginners-guide-foot-traffic-data-software-api/)).
Integrating the API is really useful if you want to e.g. make consumer-focused apps/websites to inform people to which place they should and at what time.

[image: Foot traffic heatmap]
In the picture above the BestTime.app Radar tool shows foot traffic data for popular attractions in New York City. On the left the a foot traffic prediction is shown for the whole day. The map is overlayed with a heatmap that indicates the predicted foot traffic intensity for current hour per place. Using the filters, in the right panel, you can narrow down your search by selecting for example only the quiet NYC attractions on Friday afternoon.

Disclosure: I work for BestTime.app